# strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, arrays, strlen

I have an older site using phorm.  When the form is submitted I get this error:

Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/user/public_html/form/phorm.php on line 2015

I know this is because of an upgrade to php 5.3, is there an easy method to fix that line of code to make my forms work again?

```
 if (strlen($PHORM_ALERTTO) && !strlen($PHORM_TO) && !$PHORM_INFONLY && !$ph_GotData) {
    $PHORM_TO = $PHORM_ALERTTO; //THIS IS LINE 2015





 Read the mail template file(s) and mail it (them) to the user */
  $ph_section = "user template";
  if (strlen($PHORM_ALERTTO) && !strlen($PHORM_TO) && !$PHORM_INFONLY && !$ph_GotData) {
    $PHORM_TO = $PHORM_ALERTTO; //THIS IS LINE 2015
    settype($PHORM_TO, "array");
  }
  if (isset($PHORM_TMPL) && isset($PHORM_TO) && !$ph_Abort) {
    if ($ph_debug2) echo "<B>JS:</B> Mail Template(s)<BR>";

    if (count($PHORM_TMPL) > $ph_MaxTMPL) $ph_Alerts['120'] = ph_Message("A120");

    list(,$fPHORM_TO)      = each($PHORM_TO);
    list(,$fPHORM_SUBJECT) = each($PHORM_SUBJECT);

    while ($ph_MaxTMPL-- && list($ph_key, $lPHORM_TMPL) = each($PHORM_TMPL)) {
      if ($lPHORM_TMPL == ph_GENERIC) $lPHORM_TMPL = "$ph_root/files/generic.txt";
      else                            $lPHORM_TMPL = "$ph_tpd/$lPHORM_TMPL";

      $ph_Message   = "";
      $ph_Headers   = "";
      $ph_NonHeader = "";

      $lPHORM_TO      = "";
      $lPHORM_FROM    = "";
      $lPHORM_SUBJECT = "";
      $lPHORM_HEADERS = "";

      $ph_TemplateHeaders = false;
      if (ereg("(.+) +\+h$", $lPHORM_TMPL, $ph_regs)) {
        $lPHORM_TMPL = trim($ph_regs[1]);
        $ph_TemplateHeaders = true;
      }

      if ($ph_debug8) echo "Mail Template <B>$lPHORM_TMPL</B><BR>";

      if (!$ph_Template = @implode("", file($lPHORM_TMPL))) {
        $ph_Alerts['005'] = ph_Message("A005");
        if ($php_errormsg) $ph_Alerts['005P'] = "%%%: $php_errormsg";
        continue;
      }
```

Comment: that is because, you can only use it to count strings, if you want to count an array use `count()`

Comment: all is said in the warning...

Comment: any advice what I need to change in that line of code?

Comment: if (strlen($PHORM_ALERTTO) && !strlen($PHORM_TO) && !$PHORM_INFONLY && !$ph_GotData) {
    $PHORM_TO = $PHORM_ALERTTO; //THIS IS LINE 2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your are using `strlen()` to count an array while it is supposed to use when you need to count strings. Your error is quite clear.

If you need to count an array or more just use [**`count`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) or [**`sizeof`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) functions.

Comment: @PeterEastwood error mean that your using a function `strlen` to an array, so either $PHORM_ALERTTO and/or $PHORM_TO are array, try to change to `if (count($PHORM_ALERTTO) && !count($PHORM_TO) && !$PHORM_INFONLY && !$ph_GotData) { $PHORM_TO = $PHORM_ALERTTO;`